# How do I use Ingress with basic auth but only for certain routes?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, basic-authentication, kubernetes-ingress

How do I make an ingress with basic auth on every path of the domain except on one. My ingress looks like this:
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-ingress
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: x
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: x.x.x
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: "basic-auth"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: "basic"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: x.x.x
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello
          servicePort: 80
```

What i wanna make is to have basic auth on every path except on `/successfull_login`  , when I hit `x.x.x/successfull_login` not to require credentials.
I tried making a new Ingress just with that path that doesn't use basic auth but still it require basic auth.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-successfull-login
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: x
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: x.x.x
spec:
  rules:
  - host: x.x.x
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /successfull_login
        backend:
          serviceName: hello
          servicePort: 80
```

How do i do it?

Comment: also I tried making two services properly for each ingress that point to the same deployment, but still doesn't works

Comment: The approach of using a second ingress should work. Are you using the same host name and ip for both?

Comment: @KoopaKiller yes I use the same host for both, I solved this by doing another deployment, with new docker image, just for that particular view of the web application, and also I did a new service and a new ingress. And now its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the solution adopted was separate the application view in a new docker image, also a new deployment and service was created to this new piece of code.